# In what sense is the term "pigeon" used in tennis

Tags: tennis, terminology

I have encountered the word pigeon in connection with tennis players, for example, have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pigeon+site:tennis-warehouse.com), [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pigeon+site:tennisforum.com) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pigeon+site:menstennisforums.com). It seems to be a slang term - at least I did not find it in any news article.

From the context it is clear that it has something to do with one player having bad H2H against another player. Could somebody give a clearer explanation when this word is used? Etymology of this phrase could also bit interesting. Has this originated from some common idiom in English?

Comment: From your first link, I found this: http://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/index.php?threads/how-would-you-define-this-term-pigeon.507161/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A player that is easy to beat, an easy prey. If you beat a player too many times, he/she becomes your "pigeon".

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define+pigeon

NORTH AMERICAN

informal
a gullible person, especially someone swindled in gambling or the victim of a confidence trick.

This term has been commonly used as as a slang as far as the 20's in American English.